# How can I show probability of selection change when adding stratification to a survey design

Tags: probability, survey, stratification, survey-sampling

I have a survey that uses a stratified sampling approach with optimal allocation.

The team conducting the survey has asked that we make two changes:

1. Subdivide one of the strata into smaller pieces.  Each of the new strata are fully contained inside one of the previous strata.
2. Change the sampling allocation to equal allocation to balance the workload across the teams.

These changes will be used to collect additional data in the current study.

Would making this change introduce bias?  How can I show this mathematically?

My reasoning so far is that it does not.  This is how I have thought about it.

Taking only one of the strata and treating it as a population to make reasoning easier, suppose that the population has 100 elements.  10 were selected.  The probability of any element being selected is 1/10 `P(X) = 1\10`

If I divide that population into stratum A with 30 elements and stratum B with 70 I would know the number of elements that were randomly selected in each stratum in the previous sample design.  Say 2 selected elements belong to set A.  Then the probability that any in A is selected is 2/30 `(P X | X ∈ A)`.

Likewise, if I directly select 2 elements from stratum A the probability is 2/30 or `(P X | X ∈ A)`

Unfortunately, this leads me to `(P X | X ∈ A) = (P X | X ∈ A)` which is clearly true, but not helpful for illustrating that the probability of selection of each element in a stratum has an equal probability of selection when including the elements that were randomly selected prior to the introduction of the new strata.

What is a better way to work this out?

Comment: Random sampling *per se* does not introduce bias.  *How you analyze the results* could be biased.  Thus, no analysis of the type you attempt here will be helpful until you indicate specifically what you want to analyze and how.

Comment: @whuber Another way to ask the question is: if I make this change is this still a valid random sample or are probabilities of selection no longer equal in each stratum?

Comment: One of the ways in which stratification works is to make selection probabilities different in each stratum, enabling you to focus your data-collection efforts on those parts of the population that need more data than other parts.  So, again, any random sample obtained with known (or calculable) selection probabilities and analyzed appropriately for those probabilities will be valid and can produce unbiased results using unbiased estimators.

Comment: @whuber, That is the basis of my question.  Given the methodology change after a round of samples has been drawn and data collected, how do I show that all the samples in the new strata (from the first sampling round an the second) have the same probability per strata.

Comment: The nature of this change is unclear in the wording of your question: will you be collecting additional data in a separate study?  Adding to the data in a current study?  Proposing a change to how you analyze existing data?

Comment: I have added clarification to the post, "These changes will be used to collect additional data in the current study."